# Wildcard tag favourites don't work on iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, tag-watching

I recently added the wildcard tag 'nunit*' to my favourites for SO, which maps to 7-8 different tags. When accessing it through Tags > Favourites in the app however, only questions tagged explicitly 'nunit' are shown.

Marking this a bug rather than a feature request as searching for `[tag:nunit*]` does work correctly.

Comment: Seems a legit bug to me. It does work on the web. If it doesn't work on the app, it should be fixed.

Comment: I never knew about wildcard favorites.  The gap we have is that we use endpoints like `/questions/unanswered?tagged=nunit*`  rather than `/questions/advanced?q=[nunit*]`.  I'm reworking question listings right now and will make sure to address this.

Comment: Great, thanks @BrianNickel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.4.4 as part of [new nav](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276115/stack-exchange-ios-app-is-getting-new-question-nav).

When the app detects a wildcard tag, it will use the appropriate methods and present only the supported filter and sort options.

> [image: Screenshot of wildcard tags.]