# The iOS app replaces wildcard tags when you edit any tag

Tags: bug, tag-watching, api, wildcards

[As of February this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274073/wildcard-tag-favourites-dont-work-on-ios-app), the iOS app supports wildcard tags - yay!

I've just noticed however that while the app supports loading questions from favourite wildcard tags, if you *make changes to* any of your favourite tags on the app, it removes the wildcard status from all of them.

That is, adding/editing/removing any favourite tag on a site, through the iOS app, turns all other favourite tags that *are* wildcards, into non-wildcard favourites. For example, adding `[laravel]` as a favourite on the app makes `[javascript*]` turn into just `[javascript]`. That change then takes effect both on the app and on the website.

I can temporarily work around the problem by fixing my tags when I get back to the computer, but it does appear to be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next API build.

The API was incorrectly sanitizing wildcard tags.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for responding Brian. And thanks so much for your hard work on the app, it is _very_ nicely built.